# When/why does SSH close a connection?

Tags: ssh, putty

I have a CentOS server which I access via SSH from my Windows laptop, either manually with Putty or programmatically using the Python Fabric module.

Sometimes after a period of inactivity the connection is closed.

My main question is when/why? Where are the settings that dictate when an SSH connection should close? What are the default values if none are set? I'd just like to understand the logic that goes into my connection being closed... sometimes it seems to allow a connection to remain open for well over 12 hours of inactivity while other times it seems to close the connection after just ~30 minutes of inactivity.

A secondary question is whether there's some way I can get Putty to remain open. Right now Putty just tells me that the connection was closed and has me close the window. Is there some way I could have Putty just restart the connection instead and not require me to close the windows and manually re-login?

Answer (score 0):

You have probably set up `ClientAliveCountMax 0` and some `ClientAliveInterval` option in `sshd_config` (or there is used some default value).

Setting these values to something non-zero should allow server to send keep-alive messages that will verify that client is still responding.

There should be similar option on client (in openssh called) `ServerAliveCountMax` and `ServerAliveInterval`).

This behaviour can be also resulted by using client option `TCPKeepAlive` and the same on server, but this is turned on by default.

Comment: My understanding was that if `ClientAliveCountMax` was set to `0`, that the SSH connection would never automatically close.

Comment: The server side yes. On the client side, I don't have experience with putty. But depending on the error/closing message, you should be able to recognize if connection was closed by server or client.